# connection with oracle database in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oracle11g

I am doing a database project using reactjs for frontend and Oracle database for the database connection.
 Many sources for the connection of React and MySQL are available but there is hardly any source for connection with the oracle database in React.How do i do it? documentation for nodejs oracle connection is available.so i can connect with the database but how do i show results on localhost using Reactjs?
I have tried to create a simple javascript file and connect with oracle in it.I was able to get data on the console but how do i post it on localhost?

Comment: I just started a new series on creating REST APIs with Node.js and Oracle Database: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Answer (score 0):

You need apis for acting as a bridge between reactjs application and oracle db. You can use any backend stack for oracle db connection and apis like nodejs, python etc. Reactjs is not to be used for server side applications, its only for the frontend meant to be running inside a browser.